# Create new column from conditions on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

What I'm trying to write would be written with the apply function in Python:

```
def categorise(row):  
  if row['colC'] > 0 and row['colC'] <= 99:
    return 'A'
  elif row['colC'] > 100 and row['colC'] <= 199:
    return 'B'
  elif row['colC'] > 200  and row['colC'] <= 299:
    return 'C'
  return 'D'

df['colF'] = df.apply(lambda row: categorise(row), axis=1)
```

This is the R code I have at the moment

```
myf <- function(x) {
  count <- 0
  if(x[,"BMICat"]==4){
    count = count +1}
  if(x[,"SleepTimeCat"]==1 | x[,"SleepTimeCat"]==4){
    count= count+1}
  if(x[,"MentalHealthCat"]==3){
    count= count+1}
  if(x[,"Smoking"]==TRUE){
    count= count+1}
  if(x[,"PhysicalActivity"]==FALSE){
    count= count+1}

  return(count)
}

dfAugment %>% 
mutate(BadHabits= myf(.))
```

I often get stuck on trying to apply this pattern in R, is my approach not common in R?

Comment: just do `cut(x, c(0, 100,200,300, Inf), c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))`

Comment: Note that in your ifelse statement, values like `100, 99.9, 0` etc have not been captured by the if statements but rather the return `D` part. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your aproach is not the best way to do things. Use `case_when`

Comment: @onyambu My python code is just a copy and paste from random code, I dont care about it being wrong. Would you mind explaining how would I create a count value using casee_when on multiple columns please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, a possible solution is creating dummy variables and then adding them together.

```r
library(dplyr)

dfAugment <- data.frame(BMICat = c(1, 2, 4, 4),
                        SleepTimeCat = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

dfAugment |> 
  mutate(risk_sum = if_else(BMICat == 4, 1, 0) +
                    if_else(SleepTimeCat == 1 | SleepTimeCat == 4, 1, 0))
```

Output

```r
#>   BMICat SleepTimeCat risk_sum
#> 1      1            1        1
#> 2      2            2        0
#> 3      4            3        1
#> 4      4            4        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works for sure, thank you for the answer. But I can't be dissuaded by thinking that it's an incredibly "hacky" way to solve a basic problem. Does R not have tools for this kind of stuff? Is this that much of an out of ordinary operation that I'm trying to do? I've been learning R but feature engineering seems extremely painful

Comment: I'm not an expert so I'm sure that there is a more computationally elegant way to solve the same problem. However my understanding is that R (and especially the tidyverse) works in a different way compared to other programming languages, prioritising vectorised operations and legibility over procedural programming and loops. And TBH I don't see how creating many columns based on `if_else` functions and then adding them together is fundamentally different from updating a tally based on a series of `if` statements. It seems to me that they're doing the same thing, in a different order.

Comment: I'm accustomed to the Pandas way of accomplishing the task which would be a row by row operation checking the ifs on the needed columns and then writing the outcome for the current row in the new column. I find it to be much more clean but seems like your way is how R people usually approach the problem; it just looks a bit hacky to me cause you're adding intermediate columns. Thank you

Comment: You can also simplify the code to remove the need for extra columns - see updated answer